# How should project-level bundling be handled for non SPA use?

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp, browserify, browserify-shim

I am learning browserify and I am trying to do two basic things with it:

1. Transform (via shim) non-CommonJS modules for ease-of-use and dependency tracking
2. Bundle the libraries that are project-specific

I've found a working process for how to do all of this and automate it with Gulp. This works and produces the right output but, I am curious if it could be made simpler. It seems like I have to duplicate a lot of configuration on the project-based bundles. Here is the working example:

**package.json** 
<sub>*invalid comments added for clarification*</sub>

```
{
    //project info and dependencies omitted

    //https://github.com/substack/node-browserify#browser-field
    "browser": { //tell browserify about some of my libraries and where they reside
        "jquery": "./bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js",
        "bootstrap": "./bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"
    },
    "browserify": {
        //https://github.com/substack/node-browserify#browserifytransform
        "transform": [
            "browserify-shim"
        ]
    },
    "browserify-shim": { 
       //shim the modules defined above as needed 
        "jquery": {
            "exports": "$"
        },
        "bootstrap": {
            "depends": "jquery:$"
        }
    }
}
```

**config.js** 
<sub>contains all task-runner related configuration settings</sub>

```
module.exports = {

    browserify: {
        // Enable source maps and leave un-ulgified
        debug: true,
        extensions: [],
        //represents a separate bundle per item
        bundleConfigs: [
            {
                 //I really want to refer to the bundles here made in the package.json but 
                 //if I do, the shim is never applied and the dependencies aren't included
                 entries: ['/bundles/shared-bundle.js'], 
                 dest: '/dist/js',
                 outputName: 'shared.js'
            }
        ]
    },
    //...
};
```

**shared-bundle.js** 
<sub>acts as a bundling file where node loads the dependencies and at this point, the shim has been applied</sub>

```
require('bootstrap');
```

**browserify-task.js** 
<sub>contains the browserify bundling gulp task</sub>

```
//module requires omitted
gulp.task('browserify', function (callback) {
    var bundleQueue = config.bundleConfigs.length;
    var browserifyBundle = function (bundleConfig) {
        var bundler = browserify({
            entries: bundleConfig.entries,
            extensions: config.extensions,
            debug: config.debug,
        });

        var bundle = function () {
                return bundler.bundle()
                // Use vinyl-source-stream to make the stream gulp compatible
                .pipe(source(bundleConfig.outputName))
                // Specify the output destination
                .pipe(gulp.dest(bundleConfig.dest))
                .on('end', reportFinished);
        };

        var reportFinished = function () {
            if (bundleQueue) {
                bundleQueue--;
                if (bundleQueue === 0) {
                    // If queue is empty, tell gulp the task is complete
                    callback();
                }
            }
        };
        return bundle();
    };
    config.bundleConfigs.forEach(browserifyBundle);
});
```

---

In `config.js` where the first `bundleConfig` item's `entries` is a source to a file that has the `require()` modules, I'd like replace those with module names of modules defined in the package.json `browser` key.

In the `config.js`, if I change the bundle configuration to:

```
 bundleConfigs: [
      {
           entries: ['bootstrap'], 
           dest: '/dist/js',
           outputName: 'shared.js'
      }
 ]
```

and run the gulp task, it will include bootstrap.js but it doesn't run the shim transformation. jQuery is not being included at all.

This leaves me with a few questions:

- Is there a better way to be bundling my js for use in a non-SPA application (ie am I going about this the wrong way)?
- If not, is there a way to ensure the shim transformation is run prior to the bundling so that I can have my bundle configuration in one place?

Comment: I'm confused as to what your overall goal is.  You mention "non-SPA"; can you elaborate on that?  What do your entries look like?  You mentioned that certain libraries aren't showing up.  In my experience, that means neither the entries nor a dependent of the entries refer to the library.

Comment: @pgreen2 my goal is to bundle project dependencies in an environment that isn't a single page application ie.. more traditional I guess? The code posted above _works_. What doesn't work is when I use the `browser`entries in the browserify() entries option. It can see the main package (ie bootstrap in the example) but it doesn't see its shimmed dependency jquery.

Comment: Can you throw a small project on github that demonstrates your problem that we can play with?

Comment: @CarrieKendall did you ever figure this out? Having the same issue.

Comment: @YPCrumble The code in the question works, it's just not efficient. I ended up using a config.js file to define my page-specific bundles, basically.

Answer (score 1):

Certainly, you just have to tell your gulp file that it should shim first. Looks like you can add your own `shim` object when calling browserify from your gulp file. Check out [this example](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-browserify#browserify-shim)

If you want to ensure everything is shimmed before you bundle them, use the [`deps`](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/docs/API.md#deps) array: "An array of tasks to be executed and completed before your task will run."

It would look something like this:

```
gulp.task('shim', function() {
  // ...
});

gulp.task('browserify', ['shim'], function(){
  // ...
});
```

Comment: [This](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-browserify#browserify-shim) is an interesting example, I hadn't seen that before. Your code example is kind of useless though. I might see if I can apply my shims in the task, although this is less than ideal. I guess I am still left with the question: is there no way to tell browserify to run the globally registered shims in the stream instance?

Comment: Feel free to go ahead and answer it. I'm actually not familiar with shimming. Glad the resource helped!